# How I can make Hot-keys for moving Picture Files

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I have Million pictures in my PC, and I want to classify and Sort them, each person in a separate folder.
So I make folder for my wife, another for my Son, another for my other Son etc…
Now I want to open the pictures one by one, and when I see that this picture for my wife, I will press one key, let we say “M” as first letter of her name, and this picture will be cut and past or to be send to my wife folder. And when I see that this picture is for my Son, I will press one key, let we say “D” as first letter of his name, and this picture will be cut and past or to be send to my Son folder, etc…
It will save a lot of time if I can do this, I can’t cut and past million pictures manually.
How I can do that????